# Why can't we specify default access modifier for a class

Tags: java, access-specifier

I know why private and protected are illegal modifiers for a class but why is default not acceptable. I think if we don't specify any access modifier, `default` gets assigned. But typing it explicitly like `default class Student` gives me a syntax error

Comment: There is no such access level as "default". An access level is one of these four: "public", "private", "protected", or "package-private". The last one is not a keyword, and can only be specified as the absence of a modifier. Which access is the default (when there is no modifier) depends on what the thing is and where it is; usually it's package-private, but members of interfaces are public by default, and enum constructors are private by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default access modifier in Java can be used by just omitting any access modifier. Java 8 introduced a new `default` keyword used to provide a default implementation for an interface's method but, despite its confusing name and location in the method's declaration, it has nothing to do with access modifiers.

Answer (score 1):

A class may be declared with the modifier public, and 'nomodifier' but not the meaning of instead of nomodifier 'default' key word

please go through this link
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Comment: But Java has provided `default` as a keyword. Where is it used except in default methods of interface

Comment: @Manoj The only other use of the `default` keyword is in the [`switch` statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html).